# How to keep getting data in every component of vue app?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3, capacitor

I want to build a kind of helper function in my vue app. Actually, I am using location watcher to get the current location

```
getLocation: async function () {
    

      BackgroundGeolocation.addWatcher(
        {
          // If the "backgroundMessage" option is defined, the watcher will
          // provide location updates whether the app is in the background or the
          // foreground. If it is not defined, location updates are only
          // guaranteed in the foreground. This is true on both platforms.

          // On Android, a notification must be shown to continue receiving
          // location updates in the background. This option specifies the text of
          // that notification.
          backgroundMessage: "Requerido para el rastreo en tiempo real",

          // The title of the notification mentioned above. Defaults to "Using
          // your location".
          backgroundTitle: "Rastreo Siloc",

          // Whether permissions should be requested from the user automatically,
          // if they are not already granted. Defaults to "true".
          requestPermissions: true,

          // If "true", stale locations may be delivered while the device
          // obtains a GPS fix. You are responsible for checking the "time"
          // property. If "false", locations are guaranteed to be up to date.
          // Defaults to "false".
          stale: false,

          // The minimum number of metres between subsequent locations. Defaults
          // to 0.
          distanceFilter: 0,
        },
        (location, error) => {
          if (error) {
            if (error.code === "NOT_AUTHORIZED") {
              if (
                window.confirm(
                  "Esta app necesita acceso a tu ubicación" +
                    "para poder mostrar las funciones necesarias al llegar a la huerta y/o báscula\n\n" +
                    "¿Abrir ajustes ahora?"
                )
              ) {
                // It can be useful to direct the user to their device's
                // settings when location permissions have been denied. The
                // plugin provides the 'openSettings' method to do exactly
                // this.
                BackgroundGeolocation.openSettings();
              }
            }
            return console.error(error);
          }


        this.center2 = {lat: Number(location.latitude),lng: Number(location.longitude)};

       console.log('MY',this.center2);

           this.getLocation();
          this.currentLocation(location);
        }
      ).then(function after_the_watcher_has_been_added() {

      });

      
    },
```

This function I am using it in many components . I want it to become global and keep sending me current `longitude` and `latitude` .

this watcher function continually update longitude and latitude . is that possible to make it global?

Answer (score 0):

You can store your data or function inside [Vuex](https://vuex.vuejs.org) so they are available across your entire application.

If you're storing a longitude and lattitude value inside Vuex and update (mutate) them, you'll automatically see the values update everywhere they are used.

The mutate functionality in Vuex [follows the Vue reactivity rules](https://vuex.vuejs.org/guide/mutations.html#mutations-follow-vue-s-reactivity-rules).

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion, there is no any other method to access global watcher instead of managing store. [Vuex](https://vuex.vuejs.org/) provides a good management of maintaining store globally.
see how it works from https://vuex.vuejs.org/, a smooth way to manage thing on central place, and when we render a app first time(as SPA or simple App), you just set/update state by call, and get update data location from store by getters.